# How to sleep() from kernel init?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, sleep, oscilloscope

I'm debugging some code of the kernel init with an oscilloscope by setting up values on GPIO, what is the best way to `sleep()` for a given time very early, i.e, in `ddr3_init()` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a busy loop that stops after a given time interval. This should sleep for one second (I'm not sure if it works, I put it together by looking at the time.h header):

```
#include <linux/time.h>

struct timespec start_ts = current_kernel_time();
s64 start = timespec_to_ns(&start_ts);
do {
    struct timespec now_ts = current_kernel_time();
    s64 now = timespec_to_ns(&now_ts);
} while (now - start < 1000000000ULL);
```